# iOS7 UIBarButtonItem back button to use dynamic type

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm setting the font of the title of the navigation bar to use dynamic type
i.e.

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline]};`

Which works but the back button doesn't adopt this font.
I tried

`[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

but that hasn't worked.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the only way to do it is to create a new UIBarButtonItem:

```
UIBarButtonItem *dynamicTypeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[dynamicTypeButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = dynamicTypeButton;
```